# Some Doxygen pages not in navigation pane; others have different names

Tags: markdown, doxygen

I've got a large Doxygen project which includes several text and markdown files. A few of pages generated from these files do not appear in the navigation panel. What could cause this?

The files are in the configuration file's INPUT setting, and the pages they generate are in the output -- I can display them by clicking links to them on other pages. They just aren't in the navigation panel.

Another puzzle, which I suspect is related: A few pages have one title on the page itself, and a different title in the navigation panel. All of these pages are generated from .txt or .md files, and are defined by \page commands. The title on the page comes from the \page command's second parameter. I haven't figured out where the title in the navigation pane comes from -- I've searched all of the files in/under the Doxygen project directory and the directory that contains the .txt or .md files, and it never shows up!

Comment: In case a page type of title is present at the beginning of a file doxygen will use this as name for the entry in "related pages" / "tree view" etc. the user is not really interested in the name of the file giving a description but in the topic of the file. Regarding the "missing" files can you give an example, i.e. the first few lines in a MWE (together with the setting you used that are different from the default settings, i.e. `doxygen -x`). Which version of doxygen are you using?

Comment: @albert I'm afraid you'll have to dumb that down for me. I don't know what page type is. I searched for ``doxygen "page type"`` but I didn't find anything useful. I also couldn't find a meaning for MWE. More generally -- certainly the key to the puzzle is to find the difference between pages that appear in the navigation panel and pages that don't, but I've looked hard at them and I didn't see it. The Doxygen version is 1.8.7; it runs with no switches.

Comment: Doxygen version 1.8.7 is from April 21, 2014 this is a bit old the current version is 1.8.18 or did you mean 1.8.17? MWE is a Minimal Working Example, in this case it would be a `.md` file and the settings differenet from the default doxygen settings file (from your comment I understand that you use a default version, is this correct?). I don't know many `.md` / `.txt` files you have but my approach would be list all these file in the `INPUT` setting (best on separate lines with the aid of `INPUT +=`, and remove files and see when the problem disappears / i.e. when you find the "missing" file.

Comment: 1.8.7 is indeed old, and that's an acknowledged problem, but replacing it is not simple. It's embedded in a toolchain that's complex and somewhat fragile. I don't know what the side effects of replacing it would be. /// Because the project is large (~80 source files), the MWE approach will be laborious, and I think there's a risk that complications (unknown unknowns) will impair the value of the results. I posted here hoping to avoid having to do that. If there's no clear alternative, though, I'll bite the bullet.

Comment: 80 files looks like large but I wouldn't really calling it large it also depends on the size, the doxygen src directory already contain over 280 file (but this just all as a side note). I would anyway try as a test to, locally, install the doxygen executable and patch the path calling sequence of your toolchain in such a way that the new doxygen version is used and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. There's an XML file in the project directory that defines index entries, and the missing pages weren't in it. I added them, and presto! they were included.

I thought the navigation panel was built entirely from defgroup and ingroup commands, but apparently not. Once I solved the problem I remembered that I started by looking for the defgroup/ingroup commands that defined these pages, thinking I'd add commands for the missing pages in the same place and the same way as the ones that were shown. I never found the commands. Now I know why.

Comment: Which xml file do you mean?

Comment: It's a file named by the project file's LAYOUT_FILE parameter. It's one of many parts of a project framework I use, which was created by other people. I didn't know it was there before.